With openpyxl, how can I remove the color of a row full-filled with color?
In a .xlsx file, row 1 to 3 are 'full-filled' with background colors, i.e, A1:XFD3 are colored.
They are full-filled with color in LibreOffice Calc by selecting a row and set the background color. And in row 4 to 6, only cells A4:B6 are filled with colors. See the figure below:

After running the following code that tries to remove the background color of all cells in sheet 'Sheet1':
src_fname_path = "./test_delete_row.3.xlsx"
new_fname_path = "./test_delete_row.delete.3.xlsx"
src_book = openpyxl.load_workbook (src_fname_path)
sheet = src_book ['Sheet1']

for row in sheet:
    for cell in row:
        cell.fill = PatternFill ()

src_book.save (new_fname_path)


Background colors in row 1 to 3 remain NOT changed at all, while colors in cells A4:B6 are removed entirely. See the figure below:

Is there any way I can remove the background color of all cells in row 1 to 3??

Looks like I  have to withdraw the second part of my previous comment. From investigating the underlying XML the colour is actually set for the row and not the cells when setting the whole row fill colour. Therefore setting the fill to nothing in the cell changes nothing as the cell fill is already nothing. Changing the fill on the cells does not appear to break the application to the row so even applying another fill to some cells, which will work  obviously, and then removing that fill will just return to the underlying row colour. Are you unable to run the Excel app and use Xlwings?

The code works on the cells A4 - A6 because the colour fill is applied to the individual cells, given it's not covering the whole row.

Thanks for your comments again, Moken!
"the colour is actually set for the row and not the cells when setting the whole row fill colour." --> Yes! That's how I think after doing several experiments!
Yes, as now I'm working under linux, MS Excel is not available normally.
It sounds a little bit weird to me: as a quite powerful library, openpyxl supports a lot of  features to manipulate .xlsx files, but does not provide a feature to control the color set on an entire single row. what a pity...

It's not necessarily that Openpyxl cannot or could not do this. Openpyxl is a front end to OOXML, what  the Openpyxl Devs have provided is a front end to this API. Not everything is 'accessed' or at least documented, they have enabled the common and requested features that a person would use with editing Excel. Technically it may be possible to do this with Openpyxl as is, but 'additional features' can often mean spending some time to work out the required OOXML operations and then determining how to implement. This takes time of course.

OK, I understand. Thanks again for your explanations!
By the way, "From investigating the underlying XML", I'm wondering what kind of tool you use to check the XML content? Is there any existing tool can do this?

I'm just unzipping the XLSX and looking at the xml files in an editor.

OK, it sounds easy. I'll try it. Thanks again! I wish you a good day!

What about alternate options like why do you need to retain this particular Sheet? Could you just create a new Sheet, copy over data from the original if needed and then delete the sheet with the fill from the workbook?

You can set styles for entire rows and columns using the row_dimesions and column_dimensions attributes of worksheets. However, according to the specification styles themselves are always applied to the cells and row and column styles are left to the consuming application: Excel applies them to "new" cells. Building a dependency graph can be tricky and the resolution can be even more so, which is why we leave it to code client code to decide.

@Moken: It sounds like a good alternative option. OK, let me try replacing the existing sheet with a new one. Thanks!

@Charlie: By "we leave it to code client code to decide", do you mean that I can still achieve my goal by setting styles for one entire row using row_dimesions attribute??

No, you decide in your code what you want. As the documentation says: styles should always be applied to all cells. What you see when you just set row styles will depend upon the application used to view the file.

@Charlie, OK, I see. Anyway, thanks for your reply and explanations!
